# When trying to change laptop to boot from DVD it says I cannot change it in user mode

Tags: windows, boot, laptop

I found an old computer of my dad's company and wanted to clean it so that he can stop using is 12 year old laptop, but I am having some issues with it:

**Laptop** - Fujitsu Esprimo Mobile
**OS** - MS Windows Vista Basic

1. I don't know the password of the user.

   This isn't such a big problem because we don't need the information so if I format the pc everything is fine. So let's move on tho the real problem
2. When I restart the PC and try to change the PC setting to boot by the CD/DVD, this happens to me:

[image]

It's the first time that I've seen this kind of info in the boot menu. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

You typically don't need to change the boot order to boot from optical media. You just need to invoke the boot menu options when booting. Try pressing ESC, F9, F10, F11 or F12 (one at a time) when booting until you see the boot menu. Then select the optical drive.

Comment: My first try was with ESC and i solved the problem. Thank you. So easy, yet so difficult to me. hehe.

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS is locked - it would require a password to allow you to edit these settings.  Since you don't have this password, many motherboards have a jumper on the board itself that you remove or install to clear the BIOS password.  Alternately, sometimes pulling the CMOS battery for several minutes (I am not referring to the main battery, but you should remove it also!) may clear the password.  Also, it may be necessary to power-cycle the unit a few times with the CMOS battery removed.

After resetting, you should be able to access the BIOS unrestricted.

However, @joequerty is right: there is likely a keypress or key sequence at bootup which allows you to choose CD Drive as the boot drive, without the need to enter the BIOS, although some really old systems didn't have this.  Watch the bootup screen carefully to see if it says "Press _____ for boot menu" etc.